# How to display a JTable in a JPanel with Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

How to display a JTable in a JPanel with Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imports and table model left as an exercise to the user of this code.  Also, the panel layout is arbitrarily chosen for simplicity.

```
public class JTableDisplay {
    public JTableDisplay() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Test Display");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTable table = new JTable();

        JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);

        panel.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTableDisplay();
    }
}
```

The scroll pane is fairly important to note.  Without it, your table won't have a header or scroll if the content becomes larger than the display.

Comment: How can I create and name the columns for the created table??

Answer (score 9):

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JScrollPane spTable = new JScrollPane(table);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.add(spTable);
```

There is a comphrensive guide about how to layout swing components, you should consider Pyrolistical link..