# How to assign the JPanel to JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign the auto complete text field to JTable cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880810/how-to-assign-the-auto-complete-text-field-to-jtable-cell)

I  have created a class for auto complete text fields.

I want to use that class and try to include my JTable cell fields, add that controls to one panel  but it won't display. please advice

Comment: This Link is helpful for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623957/how-to-display-a-jtable-in-a-jpanel-with-java

Comment: please don't ask the exact same question (over and over) again - instead try to understand the answers you where given last time.

Answer (score 4):

You need a cellrenderer and so...

Here is an [example](http://pekalicious.com/blog/custom-jpanel-cell-with-jbuttons-in-jtable/) for using a JPanel in a JTable cell.

Comment: This should be a comment. Otherwise please provide enough details.

Comment: Thanks for comment an post which is about 4 years old...

Comment: The website is offline but has been crawled by the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20170803143713/http://pekalicious.com/blog/custom-jpanel-cell-with-jbuttons-in-jtable/