# How to remove a jTable column from another class, in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I'm using a cardlayout, to display list of panels. In one of the panels, i have a `JTable` with several columns and rows of records. 
Now, i'd like to remove the first column of the `JTable`, depending on which user logs in. 
Below is my code(in the login `JFrame`):

```
//calling the jframe that holds the cardlayout

Home home= new Home();

//calling the panel that holds the jtable

viewRecords b =new viewRecords();

//when a user logs in

//removing the 1st column of the jtable in panel viewRecords

b.jTable1.removeColumn(b.jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));

//displaying jFrame Home

Home.setVisible(true);
```

The problem is: it works fine when using a `JFrame` to display the table, but doesn't work while using `JPanel` to display the same table. Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Is the `JTable` not even visible on the `JPanel`? Please provide some further details of your problem. Maybe this could help you too [How to display a JTable in a JPanel with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2623987/5702956)

Comment: The title combined with the first sentences of your question hints to me that the code `extends JPanel`. Is that assessment correct? I ask because extending panel is really only necessary when overriding the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, and this does not seem like that situation. Also that the model (e.g. a table model) is too tied in, to the view (the panels) where that is a poor design and should be fixed first.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the column from the view of the table:

```
public void hideColumn(int modelColumn)
{
    int viewColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToView( modelColumn );

    if (viewColumn != -1)
    {
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn column = tcm.getColumn(viewColumn);
        tcm.removeColumn( column );
    }
}
```

For a fancy implementation of this logic check out the [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/) which allows the user to hide/show columns.

Comment: @Kenn, Then you are doing something wrong. The layout manager is irrelevant. It doesn't matter if you add the table directly to the frame or to a panel and then add the panel to the frame. The problem is probable that "b.table1" does not reference the table being displayed on the panel. You need to restructure you code so you don't access variables like that. I guess the simplest solution is to add a "removeFirstColumn()" method to you class containing the table. Then you just invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

this code hide fisrt column in your jtable

```
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
```

Comment: Don't play with the widths of the TableColumn. The column is still part of the view. As the user uses the Tab key to move from column to column, the "hidden" column will still gain focus which will confuse the user.